# Any way to exclude commits from branch in git?

Tags: git, deployment

I'm looking for a way to exclude commits from a branch.

Let's say I have the branch ***master*** which I push to the production server.
 But I have commits that I do not want to push to the server. Is there any way to exclude these commits on the push?

Maybe that would be possible using tags?

Maybe you have another ideas how to work around this problem?

Comment: So you want to skip a commit or only go up to a certain point in history?

Answer (score 4):

From the get-go... this sounds like a use-case for additional [branches](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) in your workflow.  You may want to have a `main` branch that you point the production server to.  Then, when you want to make incremental commits, bugfixes, refactors, etc, then you can store those in a `development` branch.  That way, the production server can still `git pull` (from `main`) without any issues, and you can store your commits in another place.  Once the development branch is ready to go live in production, you can [`rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) your `development` branch on top of any commits that happened on `main` while you were busy elsewhere, then you can just fast-forward the commits from `development` onto `main` using [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)

This cycle is referred to as the [Feature Branch Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow) and might solve the nature of the problem you're running into.

Now... to answer your initial question, there isn't a super intuitive way to filter out specific commits when you pull from the git repository.  Not to say it can't be done... but it will take a bit of work to get there.

If I had a branch named `main` and it had commits A-B-C-D-E:

```
Newest
a2a35a479a69b62cba8c65344211d9fc3e1dc66e - E
7213fb8420ca164c3975078a498b394be3455870 - D
b6db644732c28a4f91061d812a61c37d09f8f94c - C
4dab25431e3dd747874f9488389c094e81bc96ba - B
aa2d56df73afb19043c33f4b9e8addd2d9089375 - A
Oldest
```

and I only wanted to pull commits A-B-D-E (dropping C) I would do the following:

1. [`git fetch origin main`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)

- **fetch** - Download/Obtain the commits from the remote repository, but do **not** merge them into the local copy of the named branch.
- **origin** - Name of the remote in your repository.  This is almost always named `origin`. Use `git remote -v` to see what remotes are available to fetch from and push to.
- **main** - Name of the branch you're pulling the commits from.  Use `git branch` to list the available branches.

1. [`git checkout 4dab25`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

   - **checkout** - Attempt to switch to the specified point in git's history
   - **4dab25** - The shortened sha-256 digest ([commit hash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History)) indicating which commit you want to move to.  You can view the available commit hashes using `git log`
2. [`git cherry-pick 7213f main`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)

   - **cherry-pick** - Apply changes from existing commits in other branches "out-of-order" onto the local branch
   - **7213f** - The shortened sha-256 digest ([commit hash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History)) indicating which commit you start picking commits from.
   - **main** - This could be another commit hash, but as a shortcut, I just specified `main` as a reference to the latest commit in the main branch.

If things went well, you will now have a detached HEAD with the commits A-B-D-E in order.  You may run into issues where the cherry-pick involves a merge (which is a separate issue entirely)  I don't know what you want to do from here, but you could create a new branch at this point (and start using this new branch in the future), or leave it as is until you need to cherry-pick more commits from `main` again (which sounds a little odd... I wouldn't recommend this)

Answer (score 0):

If are some commits, say 5, ahead of *origin/master*, but wish to push only some, say 2, of those, [the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) can help you: make it a topic branch

> Undo a commit, making it a topic branch
>
> ```
> $ git branch topic/wip     (1)
> $ git reset --hard HEAD~3  (2)
> $ git checkout topic/wip   (3)
> ```

then you can `push` (the first two commits) to *origin/master*, and continue working. You might just go in the *topic/wip* branch and later merge selectively, or you might merge the whole *topic/wip* branch into your local master.

The key point is

1. the `branch` command, which saves your current state to a branch
2. the `reset --hard` command, which removes the last 3 commits from master

Answer (score 0):

You need to have another branch from the master, then cherry-pick your wanted commits from there. You can view your commits by `git log`

From master

```
git checkout -b branch
git cherry-pick <sha1-of-commit>
```

Then push your branch.